# Hook to run when a hash's content changes

Tags: ruby, hash

I wan't to do something when a hash's content changes. I sub-classed `Hash`, and overrode the method `[]=` like this:

```
def []= (key,val)
  super(key,val)
  puts 'do something'
end
```

But it doesn't work when I call `merge`. What is the right way to do this? Do I have to override every method that updates the hash?

Comment: when you call `merge`, well, you call `merge`, not `[]=`.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko so I want to call a method when the hash's content changes whether by `[]=` or `merge`

Comment: _Sidenote:_ subclassing `Hash` for that is a **very bad idea**, since ruby hashes are highly optimized and this approach just ruins everything, prepending ruby code to plain old good `c` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not care about performance, you could wrap the frozen hash and delegate to wrapped frozen instance all the methods (rescuing, reporting and updating another copy.) Here you go:

```
class MyHash < BasicObject
  def initialize(hash = {})
    hash! hash
  end

  def hash!(hash)
    @hash = hash.freeze
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &λ)
    hash.send(m, *args, &λ)
  rescue => e
    raise e unless e.message.ends_with?('frozen Hash')

    # modification attempt was made
    puts 'do something'
    hash!(@hash.dup.send(m, *args, &λ)
  end
end
```

Untested, but you got the idea.

Comment: OP is asking to perform some actions when the hash changes, not when a _method is missing_; Your code will execute 'something' for any method tried, even if the method by itself does not change the hash (i.e. `[]` operator). You may create a list of methods which modify the internal state of the hash, and check it within `method_missing`. I think it's preferable to just override the desired methods as it goes.

Comment: @Wikiti if the method does not change the hash, `rescue` clause will be successfully bypassed, since `freeze` contract won’t be violated.

Comment: Interesting, that's a clever way to prevent modifications. However, it will still execute the 'do something' code even if the method does not exist. You should probably check if `@hash` respond to the missing method before trying to `send` it.

Comment: @Wikiti yeah, since I do not think this approach is of any value, I just posted a scaffolded solution; added an explicit check for whether the exception was “ours.”

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to return the accessed value, and override the `merge` method too:

```
def []= (key,val)
  out = super(key,val)
  puts 'do something'
  out
end

def merge(hash)
  out = super
  puts 'do something'
  out
end
```

Please, consider using another solution, since moneky-patching core classes is a terrible practice, which may lead to undefined behaviour (like your `merge` method failing).

Try using inheritance instead:

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def []= (key,val)
    out = super(key,val)
    puts 'do something'
    out
  end

  def merge(hash)
    out = super(hash)
    puts 'do something'
    out
  end
end

# Usage
hash = MyHash.new
hash['a'] = 42 # prints 'do something'
```

---

For a more elegant solution, you may want to check the [hooks](https://github.com/apotonick/hooks) gem.

Comment: Just to point out, this solution is still a long way off monitoring when any value changes!... What about `Hash#compact!`, `Hash#delete`, `Hash#delete_if`, `Hash#keep_if!`, `Hash#reject!`, `Hash#select!`, `Hash#store`, `Hash#transform_values!`, `Hash#update`, (and probably more that I've missed out??)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I'd also point out that overriding `Hash#merge` (as opposed to `Hash#merge!`) is possibly unnecessary - since this method is creating a new Hash, not mutating the existing one.